# how to do login with html template in laravel 5.5 and store in mysql database

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I need a solution for this question. How to do login with html template in laravel 5.5

I have a html template which i have changed in to blade.php inside my laravel project. By keeping all the html in views and css, js , images in public folder.

I have provided the routes to the files and also register controller and models are written properly but data is not getting stored in the database.

Html codes in home.blade.php. Added the form action as in the auth file method

```
<!-- login -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="login px-4 mx-auto mw-100">
                        <h5 class="text-center mb-4">Login Now</h5>
                        <form action="{{ route('login') }}" method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="mb-2">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit mb-4">Login</button>
                            <p class="text-center pb-4">
                                <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                            </p>
                            <p class="text-center pb-4">
                                Don't have an account?
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter2">Create one now</a>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- //login -->
    <!-- register -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="login px-4 mx-auto mw-100">
                        <h5 class="text-center mb-4">Register Now</h5>
                        <form action="{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>E-Mail</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="mb-2">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmpassword" id="password2" placeholder="" required="">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit mb-4">Register</button>
                            <p class="text-center pb-4">
                                <a href="#">By clicking Register, I agree to your terms</a>
                            </p>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--//register-->
```

Laravel route file for directing to all the pages

```
//route to home page
Route::get('/home', function () {
        return view('pages.home');
    });

//route to contact page
Route::get('/contact', function () {
        return view('pages.contact');
    });

//route to about page
Route::get('/about', function () {
        return view('pages.about');
    });

//route to portfolio page
Route::get('/portfolio', function () {
        return view('pages.portfolio');
    });
```

User.php Model for saving in to the database

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Register Contoller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
     */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data) {
        return Validator::make($data, [
                'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data) {
        return User::create([
                'name'     => $data['name'],
                'email'    => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            ]);
    }
}
```

Login Controller: Function for user login

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

The registered user data is not getting saved in the mysql database.
Also configured data in .env file for database.
If possible provide a way or documentation to completely change a html template to laravel with login, register and create post. So, that i could understand the framework

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196606/discussion-on-question-by-karthik-how-to-do-login-with-html-template-in-laravel).

Comment: Do anyone know any documentation which completely change a html template with it's own login and register page to laravel's login, register and create post. So, that i could understand the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the solution you are looking for exists at all but from what i understand, you want to use laravel authentication in your premade template. First thing i see you are missing is routes. You should run `php artisan make:auth` and it will give you the routes needed for laravel to make auth work. you can check this by `php artisan route:list`

Comment: I have tried that solution as It gives me Laravel Default login screen but I don't want that I have my own screen. Will try your suggested way and find a way to bypass the default login page.

Comment: You can easily change the default login page with your own styling. The only thing you have to take from the default login page is form element and the routes that it uses. Divs spans inputs etc. anything can be absolutely changed by you as long as you do the form part right. Keep the form element, change the classes with your own classes , you will see :) hope it helps.

Comment: Okay It Worked.